Does anyone know what’s the earliest surviving Japanese animated sound film?
I do know The Neighbor's Wife and Mine is the earliest surviving Japanese live action sound film but I couldn’t find anything that mentions the earliest surviving Japanese animated sound film.

Chikara to Onna no Yo no Naka, 1933, is first talkie but is considered lost.

According to https://tohostudiopedia.fandom.com/wiki/Photo_Chemical_Laboratories

The exact first film after the establishment of "P.C.L. Film Factory" is the first fixed-sound animation movie called Ugokie kori no tatehiki, released on December 31, 1933 and directed by Ikuo Oishi (1901-1944) who is known as Japan's First Anime Director.




Chikara to Onna no Yo no Naka, 1933, is first recorded talkie/sound anime but is considered lost. The director, Kenzo Masaoka was considered the first to use cel animation (Chagama Ondo (The Dance of the Chagamas), 1934) and recorded sound in anime. (He made two other shorts after this, though were not released until 1934, which may have been talkies/sound but locating them is difficult though they are listed as surviving. Chagama Ondo is often shown with sound but I am uncertain if it was originally presented that way, and if it was actually a record talkie)
Prior to this, earlier shorts like Kuro Nyago (Black Cat, 1929) and Mura Matsuri (Village Festival, 1930) are silent as they have no optic track, instead they are a Record Talkie where the song was recorded onto a record and played simultaneously with the film. In the restoration process since then they have had the record synced and so it would appear to be an early anime, with sound, at first glance. This may also be the case with National Anthem, Kimigayo, from 1931, which initially was a record talkie but is also presented as a 16mm film with sound. Many early anime, 1930s onwards, are presented this way online without clarity as to when the sound was added.
Early animation history in japan is hampered by most being lost during 1923 great kanto earthquake, the domination of traditional benshi alongside silent films (live narration) until mid-1930s, wars interrupting and destroying, and the perception at the time that next to live action it is frivolous and unimportant and essentially a throw away medium.
related:
https://animation.filmarchives.jp/en/works/view/91355
https://www.tofugu.com/japan/silent-era-anime/
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/272871347_Los_pioneros_olvidados_del_anime_el_caso_de_Kenzo_Masaoka
http://www.midnighteye.com/features/pioneers-of-japanese-animation-at-pifan-part-1/
http://www.midnighteye.com/features/pioneers-of-japanese-animation-at-pifan-part-2/
https://eac.libguides.com/c.php?g=723550&p=5215189
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_anime_by_release_date_(pre-1939)
https://asiatimes.com/2017/05/rare-japanese-anime-goes-online-mark-100th-anniversary/
https://animation.filmarchives.jp/en/index.html
https://animation.filmarchives.jp/en/works/view/91355
https://www.nfaj.go.jp/wp-content/uploads/sites/5/2021/01/201008-09s.pdf
